# Update product qty through CSV on FTP

Tags: magento-1.9, product, csv, quantity

I have a CSV on the FTP server that is generated by our EPOS system. I'd like to use this CSV file to update automatically (every day) the quantities available for the products in my store.

The issue is the column headers in the CSV do not match Magento field exactly. For example, 'SKU' is defined in the CSV as 'Product-Code'.

Can anyone suggest/recommend a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities that you could go with, I'll write only about the 4 first that came to my mind.

- Update your CSV files with separate function to meet the headers, after that run the import that's scheduled right after this task.
- Extend the base Magento importer in your custom module and rewrite/add a few things.
- Create a module that would use shell and write the importer manually. No header information needed then. There are many libraries to make work on CSV files easier and faster. There's also built-in Varien_File_Csv which unfortunately doesn't have much options.
- Use existing module that have this functionality already done, some of most popular:

  -- https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport
  -- https://github.com/ho-nl/magento1-Ho_Import
  -- https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport